# how to make multiple labels visible 0 c# wfapp

Tags: c#, label, visible

it works but what if I have 100 labels? I can't type it 100 times, is there anything to hide all labels

```
    private void xd()
    {
        foreach(var c in new Panel[] {panel1, panel2, panel3, })
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Filter the Labels by Type. For example,

```
foreach (var label in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    label.Visible = false;
}
```

This can be further developed if you need to filter based on particular naming pattern,

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x=>x.Name.StartsWith("la"))
```

Similarly you can use additional filters if required to further filter your controls.

PS: btw, your example shows Panel. If you meant Panel, replace the type with Panel.

Comment: ty very much  it warks great

Comment: @flemethwow Glad to help you, kindly mark it as answer if it helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: can't 5 minutes, i will